# How to create a drill down graph using apache superset?

Tags: apache-superset

Is it possible to create a drill down graph with apache superset?
Say for example - population of all countries and onclick of a country, population of all states within that country should be drawn and onclick of state, population of state should be drawn.
Can someone help me with steps/tips to create this using apache superset as I did not find any example/option to create the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a walkthrough on this from ApacheCon Asia 2022 on youtube - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7YnpKLZ1PRM
More than I can summarize here for you

Comment: The video is about idea how to implement drill down feature and its challenges. It does not provide a working solution.

Answer (score 2):

Preset, which uses Apache Superset, has implemented a feature for Drilling to Chart details. You can find more information about it here:
https://docs.preset.io/docs/drilling-to-chart-details

There is also a pull request for a drill down prototype but I don't think it was integrated to Superset, according to the comments.
https://github.com/apache/superset/pull/14688

Including this article link here in case anyone finds it helpful (How to implement a custom drill down): https://www.tetranyde.com/blog/superset-viz-plugin-custom

Answer (score 1):

Please see the response of mistercrunch (one of the creators of Apache Superset) below or here: https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/issues/2890.

> Drill down assumes the framework is aware of hierarchies which Superset isn't at the moment. We encourage our users to slice and dice by entering the explore mode, applying filters and altering the "Group By" field which is pretty easy and very flexible. It's an open field instead of a guided flow.

Answer (score -9):

It is possible by using custom JavaScript and charts.

Comment: please share example

Comment: This is not an answer.